# Creating New Object of Other Class dynamicly?

Tags: java, object

I am tryıng to create new object of other class ın a for loop. like

```
for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
 Computer  p1=new Computer(10,20);
}
```

and when I try anywhere to reach p1.someAction();  it say you must declare p1. But if I declare it on top of program how can I create again in loop? I also try only Computer p1; but it gave exeption ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p1` only exists within the scope of the containing block. i.e. within `{...}`.

So you either need to use p1 within this block, or (and I suspect this is what you want) store each `Computer` object in a collection (say, an `ArrayList`) and use them outside the loop.

e.g.

```
List<Computer> ps = new ArrayList<Computer>();
for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
 ps.add(new Computer(10,20));
}
// now use the list contents here...
```

Comment: )) Aa... yes..I have already list of this object.I didnt thougt get from them list..))Thanks ..it was stupid question ))